# SIGABRT Error using NavController in the PopOverController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, xcode4.2

I have posted similar question previously, but this time I am providing some code for analysis. I am creating PopOverController in my AppDelegate.m file and I am adding a NavigationController variable which I want to pass to PopOverController.m file so that using that I want to push other views. Here is how I am creating the PopOver in AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if([viewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]){
        NSInteger index = [[self tabBarController] selectedIndex];
        CGRect buttonFrame = [[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] subviews] objectAtIndex:index+1] frame];

        PopOverViewController *popoverContentController = [[PopOverViewController alloc]init];

        UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:popoverContentController];

        popoverContentController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(250, 85);
        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popoverContentController];            

        NSLog(@"X:%f Y:%f",buttonFrame.origin.x,buttonFrame.origin.y);

        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:buttonFrame inView:self.tabBarController.tabBar permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];

    }
}
```

And in my PopOverController.m I am trying to use the NavigationController to choose views like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    sendFeedback *sendEmailViewController = [[sendFeedback alloc]initWithNibName:@"sendFeedback" bundle:nil];
    downLoad *downloadFilelViewController = [[downLoad alloc]initWithNibName:@"downLoad" bundle:nil];

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:sendEmailViewController animated:YES];
   else
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:downloadFilelViewController animated:YES];
}
```

But when I click on my TabBar item for the PopOver I am getting this SIGABRT message :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'The content view controller argument must be the root of its associated view controller hierarchy.'

Any reason why this is appearing? Is there somewhere I am making a mistake in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popoverContentController];
```

you are trying to put a popover controller in a navigation controller. I don't think you want this.

To put navigation in popover, you should do this,

```
UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
popoverContentController = [UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:navcon]
```

and init the navigation controller with the viewController you want, like TableViewController or something else.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I have still one question left. It is about the viewController which I need to init, I have 2 viewControllers namely FirstVC and SecondVC and I have two TabBar items for these two viewControllers. When I click on 2nd TabBar item, PopOver pops up and in that PopOver I have a table view which as two items, when clicked which leads to another 2 ViewControllers depending upon rowSelected. So I want to show this VC's from my PopOver. So which ViewController I should init with NavigationController. Would be helpful if you could answer